# Fast development for Apps with Phonegap

Tags: cordova

I have read and analyse some examples of creating Apps with Phonegap and I have seen, that the whole development process if I work in Eclipse with the emulators is very slow.

I thought maybe I can develop all the JavaScript and Templates stuff on normal browser, debug there very fast and create the screens and after that, when there is coming the time for using some special stuff for the mobile phone like camera or database, then to copy the whole project to the asset/www folder and make there the final implementation.

What do you thing? Will be this possible, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, for example you can ..

1. create it as a web app using html 5, javascript and css;
2. use a library like jQuery Mobile, you'll be creating a one-page app (in index.html) and jQuery Mobile will provide lots of useful phone UI functionality (that will work on different phone browsers - which means that phonegap can create apps targeting different platforms);
3. test it in the browser;
4. add the Ripple Emulator to the Chrome browser to test looks and functionality in the phone emulator;
5. test it out as a web app that would run on a phone;
6. as you suggest, copy all the web app files into the www folder.
7. now add the phoneGap functionality, build the app and start testing it on real phones;

I found that by developing and testing it as a web app first, I could get user feedback and fix bugs much quicker.  It is a great way to quickly build a phone app.

Comment: using cordova fast i am having huge trouble no matter what i do i can't get most functions to work..all return 'can't call method of beep of undefined' but some of them works in my phone. But most dont work anywhere.

Comment: it was a version problem

Answer (score 1):

For Android development you really need to use an actual device. simulator works fine for iOS, but the android emulator is painfully slow and isn't much like the actual end user experience.

You are on the right track with using a desktop browser though - refreshing a web page is a lot quicker than running a full build.

I generate the app HTML with jekyll --auto --server, so the desktop preview is always on http, which makes detecting phonegap fairly easy.

Below is my app startup code - full working code is at https://github.com/tqc/ChondricJS/blob/master/src/app.js

```
    if (settings.mightBePhoneGap && document.location.protocol == "file:") {
        // file protocol indicates phonegap
        app.isPhonegap = true;
        app.platform = "cordova";
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
            console.log("appframework deviceready");
            console.log(device.platform);
            app.isSimulator = device.platform.indexOf("Simulator") > 0;
            $(initInternal);
        }

        , false);
    } else {
        // no phonegap - web preview mode
        app.platform = "web"

        $(initInternal);
    }
```

In your app code, check app.platform so you don't try to call any plugins form the desktop browser which will not have those plugins available.

Answer (score 1):

That's the idea behind [NS Basic/App Studio](http://www.nsbasic.com/app/). It gives you a nice IDE with a drag and drop design screen, templates for jQuery Mobile objects and common libraries. It produces a web app you can test in the browser, then has a Make App using PhoneGap option.

You can program in JavaScript or in a dialect of Basic very much like VB.

(Disclosure - I work for NS Basic. It's been a lot of fun making this product!)

Comment: Great solution, but the first line "Develop on Windows" is problem of mine :-)

Comment: We're big Mac fans here, but there is no native version. It does run well with Parallels, VMWare, etc.

Comment: Good news! We have released a native Mac version now as well!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this application to simplify your development!

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.Bellinux.CordovaFast

Answer (score 0):

What I do is just upload all my javascript files to a webserver and use those.

Like this, my Samsung uses the JS files from the server and uploading these files goes much faster then rebuilding and restarting the app using phoneGap any time you make small changes in your javascripts.

Of course, this does not handle all the problems (trying different phones) but for me it works great.

Don't forget to use the local copies later when you're ready, otherwise you'll always need an internet connection for your app ;)